# /usr/sbin/fanctl: No such file or directory in /etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan"

Tags: 16.04, networking, fan

After upgrading my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS virtual server the network didn't come up any more and server was unreachable.

My provider had to uncomment the line

```
/usr/sbin/fanctl net "$MODE" "$IFACE"
```

to get things running again.
Is this a known bug?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1551747

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this happen after I installed and later removed Docker.  The Docker daemon depends on FAN so it gets installed, but if you don't purge it upon removal the startup script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` sticks around.  Remove it with `apt remove --purge ubuntu-fan`.

Comment: Maybe give a reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 6):

The program you mentioned is packaged as `ubuntu-fan`. It was a dependency of Docker:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan
Reverse Depends:
  docker.io
  docker.io
```

FAN is an IP over IP tunnel protocol which does network range remapping. [This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FanNetworking) seems to be related.

This package has [the following files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ubuntu-fan/filelist):

```
$ apt-file list ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-ubuntu-fan.conf
ubuntu-fan: /etc/default/ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/dnsmasq.d/ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/init.d/ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/init/ubuntu-fan.conf
ubuntu-fan: /etc/network/if-down.d/ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/network/if-post-down.d/ubuntu-fan
ubuntu-fan: /etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan # <<<<<
ubuntu-fan: /lib/systemd/system/ubuntu-fan.service
ubuntu-fan: /usr/lib/ubuntu-fan/fan-net
ubuntu-fan: /usr/sbin/fanatic
ubuntu-fan: /usr/sbin/fanctl
ubuntu-fan: /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-fan/README
ubuntu-fan: /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-fan/changelog.gz
ubuntu-fan: /usr/share/doc/ubuntu-fan/copyright
ubuntu-fan: /usr/share/man/man8/fanatic.8.gz
ubuntu-fan: /usr/share/man/man8/fanctl.8.gz
ubuntu-fan: /var/lib/ubuntu-fan/config/README
```

The file */etc/network/if-up.d/ubuntu-fan* should be installed by default. It may be accidentally removed. You may want to purge this package and reinstall it back.

Its dependencies are [listed on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-fan). It seems to be pulled [as recommendation for docker.io package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/docker.io). Virtual servers usually have Docker installed.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The server is a virtual server - it has no fan and needs no fan control. I wonder how there was some mention of the fan issue in the first place.

Comment: It is FAN, not fan (from package description "FAN is an IP over IP tunnel protocol which does network range remapping."). This [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FanNetworking) seems to be related.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting the TLA (Three Letter Acronym). I still wonder why the server would hang after an upgrade. Why would I need to install this package? What dependencies does it have? I did an apt-get autoremove and may be that remove it since some dependency is not properly documented in the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS distribution. So is it a bug?

Comment: I do not know this FAN. Its dependencies are [listed on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-fan). It seems to be pulled as [recommendation for docker.io package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/docker.io).

Comment: please edit your answer / approve my edit.